# Apache log showing most requests as coming from my server public ip

Tags: apache, logging

It has been like a week where all my access logs are being filled with my own server IP. Like I see for example GoogleBot in my logs but instead of it showing that this is coming from a Google IP, it shows as coming from my server's public IP.

We are using CloudFlare since like a month now, but the issue started like a week ago.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, hopefully it would help anyone else facing the same issue.

We have cloudflare railgun activated, and our server admin forgot to put a line in the httpd conf file.

```
CloudFlareRemoteIPTrustedProxy Server_Public_IP_Address
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Apache is installed behind a front-end web server (like nginx). In this case Apache will see front-end's IP instead of user IPs by default. You have to install a special module for Apache like `mod_rpaf` to make it see real IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nothing is in front of Apache except cloudflare

Comment: Do you have a [mod_cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170836-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-Apache-Web-Servers-) ?

Comment: yes. mod_cloudflare have been installed so that we can capture real request ips. Could this be the issue, maybe a wrong config or something?